# Error al instanciar clase en constructor en PHP

Tags: php, poo, php8

Esta es la siguiente estructura que tengo

```
- Proyectos
  - Clases
    - Errores.php
    - Configurador.php
```

**Errores.php** contiene este código:

```
<?php
namespace Classes;
class Errores{
    private array $errores;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->errores = [];
    }
    public function addError(String $error) {
        $this->errores[] = $error;
    }
    public function dumpErrors() {
        return $this->errores;
    }
}
?>
```

**Configurador.php** contiene este código:

```
<?php
namespace Classes;
//  Externos
use Directory;
use Exception;
//  Internos
use Classes\Errores;
use Classes\Strings;

class Configurador {
    private Directory|String $rutaConfiguracion;
    private stdClass $object;
    private String|Null $objectToFind;
    private Errores$errores;

    public function __construct(Directory|String $rutaConfiguracion, String $objectToFind = null) {
        // ...
        $this->errores = new Errores(); // Linea 25
    }

    public function loadSettings(Bool $asArray = true) : array|stdClass {
        // ...
        if(!$this->couldLoaded()){
           $this->errores->addError("No se pudo añadir la configuración");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Para mi sorpresa en Configurador.php me dice:
`Uncaught Error: Class &quot;Classes\Errores&quot; not found in D:\Trabajos\FP\2 FPS\DAW\DWSE\2EVA\Ejercicios\Tema_7\classes\Configurador.php:25`

La línea 25 es la instancia de la clase Errores en el constructor de Configurador... Qué es lo que tengo mal, cómo lo corrijo. Es mi primera vez usando namespaces.

Estoy usando PHP-8.1, adjunto imagen de lo que me sale:
[image: Error que me sale]

Comment: No necesitas importar la clase con `use Classes\Errores;` ya que ambos están bajo el mismo **namespace** `Classes`. Elimina los **use**

Comment: Como tienes configurado la autocarga en composer..?? deberías agregarla a la pregunta, creo que de allí viene tu error

Comment: @Josbert Hola, no se de lo que estás hablando de composer, unicamente tengo mis clases en PHP y ya, es PHP sin librerías ni nada. He quitado los use y sigue diciendome lo mismo, añado foto

Comment: Ese es el problema, si no usas composer para cargar tu estructura de **Clases** y tampoco hace un [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.require.php) o [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) de los otros archivos **PHP** que contienen las clases, evidentemente no existen. Al ejecutar `Configurador.php` solo se ejecutara ese archivo, aunque agreges las demás clases con los `use` no se incluirán los demas archivos o clases